# View is not inflated on returning to the tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have one activity named rootActivity , in which i have a rootContainer in which i replace the fragments.

Now, the first fragment that i replace is DashboardFragment.

I now click on the cross to open a new fragment like this...
Now when i press the back button the content of dashboard fragment is lost.

Can someone help me

Here's a video to show what's really happening.
https://youtu.be/NobqYUCEZKY

Code for the **DashboardFragment**(contains the fragments inside tabs)

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private View rootView;

    /**
     *
     * @param config : For setting up stuff by the given config
     * @return
     */
    public static DashboardFragment newInstance(Bundle config) {

        DashboardFragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(config);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dashboard, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((RootActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TrackeesFragment(), "Trackee");
        adapter.addFragment(new TrackersFragment(), "Trackers");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post a code where u replace the fragment on click of cross?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try by changing the following line in

```
setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {}
```

Change

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

To

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: Can you guide why to do this ? In the meanwhile ill try it

Comment: It worked like a charm, Can you share why this works ? Because the adapter does belong to the activity and therefore using getActivity is wrong ?

Comment: Honestly, don't have much depth knowledge of the reason, but with getChildFragmentManager() you get a different instance of FragmentManager, so the Tabs fragment & your new fragments are separate & won't conflict. Also note that if now, you want to replace another fragment from your child fragment then call "getParent().getFragmentManager()" instead of "getFragmentManager()"